# How to check check if a string contains a specific character(s) using range() functions and bools in Python?

Tags: python, string, for-loop, range, substring

I'm trying to check in Python GUI if the user's email is valid after every key release. So I set global bool variables, which are `at` and `dotcom` for email validity, but every time I input a valid email format. the bools are still set to false.
This is my function for checking the email validity

```
def keyup_email(e):
global at
global dotcom

for x in range(len(custemail.get())): #gets email length after every key release
    if custemail.get()[-1] == "@" and x > 3: #check if inputted email contains "@" after typing it
        at = True
        print("at is" + str(at))
    else:
        c_email_format.config(text="Bad email")
        at = False
        print("at is" + str(at))
    if x > 5 and custemail.get()[-4:] == ".com" and at == True: #check if inputted email's last 4 characters is ".com"
        dotcom = True
        print("dotcom is" + str(dotcom))
    else:
        c_email_format.config(text="Bad email")
        dotcom = False
        print("dotcom is" + str(dotcom))
    if at == True and dotcom == True:
        c_email_format.config(text="Good email")
```

These are my GUI widgets used for email validation

```
c_email = Label(window, text="Customer Email:", width=15, height=1, bg="yellow")
c_email.grid(column=1, row=4)
custemail = StringVar()
custemail = Entry(window, textvariable=custemail)
custemail.grid(column=2, row=4)
custemail.bind("<KeyRelease>", keyup_email)
c_email_format = Label(window, text="[a-z]@[a-z].com", width=15, height=1, bg="yellow")
c_email_format.grid(column=3, row=4)
```

Every key release after inputting @ and .com still prints out `at` and `dotcom` as `false` when I tried debugging the cause of the problem. I searched ahead on strings, range functions, substrings, and conditionals, but I'm still clueless as to why my bools are still outputting `false`, which means that only `else` condition is the only functioning conditional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are doing some strange things. You iterate over the length of the email, but then you don't use the iterator to check the values. Also you overwrite every True statement, because you don't check if it is already True. e.g. if you already found an '@' you still check for it afterwards and set at to False again.

I have two solutions for you my friend. One is a cleaned up version of your code:

```py
def keyup_email(e):
  global at
  global dotcom
  email = custemail.get()
  for x in range(len(email)): #iterate over the whole email
    if not at: #if we found an '@' already, we don't want to check again to overwrite it
      at = email[x] == "@" and x > 3 #we can just set at to the result of the boolean operation
    print("at is" + str(at))
    if not dotcom: #if we found 'dotcom' already, we don't want to overwrite it
      dotcom = x > 5 and email[x:] == ".com" and at #again, we can just set dotcom to the boolean value
    print("dotcom is" + str(dotcom))
    if at and dotcom: #as at and dotcom are boolean we don't have to do an '== True'-check 
      c_email_format.config(text="Good email")
    else:
      c_email_format.config(text="Bad email")
```

Problem with this is, that you still need to reset at and dotcom when you delete a key, because then we need to check everything again.

An alternative would be to use 're' to check for a regex:

```py
import re

def keyup_email(e):
  contains_at = re.search("@", custemail.get()) #check whether email contains an '@' symbol
  ends_with_dotcom = re.search('\.com$', custemail.get()) #check whether email ends with '.com'
  if(contains_at != None and ends_with_dotcom != None): # if neither contains_at nor ends_with_dotcom are None, we found a valid email
    c_email_format.config(text="Good Email")
  else: 
    c_email_format.config(text="Bad Email")
```

Comment: I tried your cleaned up version of the code but I get "TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable" in the console after every key release. regex method works fine. However, is there a way to fix the cleaned up version? I'd my code for email validation to be close to it.

Comment: It seems if forgot the brace on one line. I edited it, and refactored the `custemail.get()` into a variable `email`, so there wonn't be any typo's in the future ^^

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now! I'll think of a way to make it set to false if @ or .com are deleted while typing the email input.

Comment: I hope you don't mind but how do I make my old code check the iterator to check the values? I tried `if custemail.get()[-x:] == "@" and x > 3:` and `if x > 5 and custemail.get()[x-4:] == ".com" and at == True:` as an example since x is the iterator variable, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Could you elaborate, what is not working? I would generally advise you to use print-statements to have a sort of debug mechanism. You could do something like `print("DEBUG - x:", x, "custemail.get()[-x:] :", custemail.get()[-x:], "custemail.get()[x-4:]", custemail.get()[x-4:])` before the first if statement to debug the corresponding values and see their content. Maybe then, you see yourself where the problem lies

Comment: my conditionals for checking the string don't seem to work (the `if` conditionals). Every time I input a valid email address, it tends to skip my conditionals that are supposed to change the values of `at` and `dotcom` to `true`, and immediately sets them to `false`.

Comment: As I mentioned, there are multiple problems. One is the that you are checking the conditionals even if you already set them to True. So if you have: `test@t` typed at will be false, because the last iteration checks if `'test@t'[-5:] == "@"` which is false. Also I think you want to check to current character, so it should be `custemail.get()[x] == "@"` instead, else you check a substring which will get longer with every iteration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227442/discussion-between-nationboneless-and-kuromiu).